# How to customize a plugin in vue.js with options parameter?

Tags: vue.js

Vue.js plugins are plain javascript object with install method:

```js
first-plugin.js(plugin file):
    
export default {
   // called by Vue.use(FirstPlugin)
   install(Vue, options) {
    
   }
}


main.js:
    
import FirstPlugin from "./plugins/first-plugin.js";
    
Vue.use(FirstPlugin);
```

How can I pass values to the options parameter(of the install() method)?

Answer (score 3):

`Vue.use(FirstPlugin, { someOption: true })`

Second parameter will be passed to `install` function as an `options` argument